# JPA: create constraint between primary key column in one table and a non-primary column in another?

Tags: jpa

I’m using JPA and trying to figure out how to create a unique constraint between a primary key column in one table and a non-primary key column in another. I have two tables:

```
Customer (
    id character varying(32) NOT NULL,
    customer_name character varying(50)
)
```

and

```
Account (
    id character varying(32) NOT NULL,
    account_name character varying(50)
)
```

There is a unidirectional, one-to-many relationship between Customer and Account with a constraint that Account.account_name is unique per Customer. The code looks like so:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @Column(length=32)
    private String id;

    @Column(unique=true, length=50)
    private String customer_name;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Account> accounts;
    ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Account {
    @Id
    @Column(length=32)
    private String id;

    @Column(length=50)
    private String account_name;
    ...
}
```

A join table is created by default:

```
CUSTOMER_ACCOUNTS (
    customer_id character varying(32),
    accounts_id character varying(32)
)
```

How do I create the unique constraint to ensure an Account.account_name is unique per Customer?

Comment: Is modifying the schema an option? If you get rid of the join table, the unique restriction is trivial.

Comment: What schema change(s) would you recommend, and how would they be expressed in JPA?

Comment: Szilágyi Donát nailed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a JoinColumn annotation to the Customer class::

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @Column(length=32)
    private String id;

    @Column(unique=true, length=50)
    private String customer_name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer")
    @JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
    private List<Account> accounts;
    ...
}
```

Referenced column name points to the primary key of the Customer table, while name points to the foreign key field of the Account table.
You should also add a CUSTOMER_ID field and a composite unique constraint to the account entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(
    uniqueConstraints=
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"CUSTOMER_ID", "ACCOUNT_NAME"})
)
public class Account {
    @Id
    @Column(length=32)
    private String id;

    @Column(length=50)
    private String account_name;

    @Column(name="CUSTOMER_ID")
    private String customer_id;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can this be done in a uni-directional manner? Our project's been trying to adhere to that, if possible. (Not my idea.)

BTW, we're using JPA to generate the DDL.

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting an exception related to the "mappedBy":  "Customer.accounts declared that it is mapped by "customer", but that is a not a field of the related type." What does "customer" in the mappedBy refer to?

I see that the JavaDoc says "mappedBy" is "the field that owns the relationship and is required unless the relationship is unidirectional.

Comment: I just had to remove the mappedBy element and things are working now. Thanks! Related question: Since customer_id is just a foreign key, and I'm using JPA to generate the schema, is there a way in JPA to make it explicit? For example, if someone looks at the Account table structure it would be nice to see something like:
FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES Customer(id)

Comment: What JPA implementation do you use?

Comment: We're using OpenJPA 2.2